# I have a few questions about Authorize.Net

Tags: e-commerce, payment-gateway, payment, authorize.net

My customer has revenues of 10.000 per week so I'm looking for a professional solution. I need a good payment gateway for my shop (Drupal Ubercart). I was considering to use Authorize.Net. Is it available in Europe ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not available in Europe. It is only available for US based merchant accounts. You can take European credit cards through Authorize.Net but only if you have a US merchant account.

From their FAQ

> At this time, we are only able to offer our services to U.S. based businesses, or merchants who have U.S. based merchant accounts.

Answer (score 1):

If you are in europe, please consider [Ogone](http://www.ogone.com).

Answer (score 1):

SagePay, Wirecard, and CyberSource are all good gateways in Europe. I've had really good experience with the support staff at Wirecard in particular.

Answer (score 1):

For those that stumble upon this question, Authorize.net now supports UK and European businesses: http://www.authorize.net/en-GB/

I believe they're also adding support for Canadian businesses as well.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you consider PayPal it is one of the widely most supported Payment Gateways, it works in Europe as you requested and from my knowledge is easily integrated/setup with ubercart.

Comment: because my customer doesn't want to provide shop information to them. He would like to use something without the need to contact the gateway payment company.

Comment: Bad suggestion to use PayPal for such revenue because PayPal can't block you at any time without any reason and explanation. For such revenue the best idea is go with Merchant Account and don't use any 3rd party sales gateaway.

Answer (score -1):

In my opinion Authorize.net is the best payment gateway out there.

**Also to quote their FAQ's:**

> Does Authorize.Net support
>   international transactions?Yes.
>   Merchants can submit transactions to
>   the payment gateway on behalf of
>   non-U.S. customers. To do so, the
>   merchant's bank account must be with a
>   financial institution located in the
>   United States, and the merchant must
>   be configured to accept the customer's
>   card type: Visa, MasterCard, American
>   Express, Discover, JCB, Diner's Club,
>   or EnRoute. The payment gateway will
>   submit the amount of the transaction
>   to the customer's card issuer, who
>   will then handle all currency
>   conversion to U.S. dollars. Since
>   default Address Verification Service
>   (AVS) settings may cause foreign
>   transactions to be declined, merchants
>   who plan to regularly accept
>   international transactions should make
>   sure that their AVS settings are
>   configured to meet their business
>   needs.

So this is the one I would choose and it is not very hard to implement.